# Android start external intent action then reopen your app

Tags: android, android-intent

I start a partner (external) app (with a custom intent action) like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.myapp.action.MY_ACTION");
i.putExtra("param1", "value1");
...
startActivity(i);
```

The partner app is then launched and the action is performed.
My problem is when re-opening my app (after pressing home button for example), the view displayed is the partner app and I have to press the device back button to go back to my app.
Is there a way to stay in my app when re-opening it?

Thanks

Comment: No, the user has to go back from the partner app's activity or the partner app needs to finish its activity when it has completed the user action.

Comment: @Karakuri actually, that isn't true. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Launch the partner app into a new task. If the user returns to your application (via HOME key press or from the list of recent tasks), your app will appear, not the partner app:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.myapp.action.MY_ACTION");
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.putExtra("param1", "value1");
...
startActivity(i);
```